# Inconsistent polygon transparency with terra::polys

Tags: r, polygon, mapping, transparency-opacity, terra

Using terra 1.7-23, when adding polygons to an existing map with the polys function, the alpha argument works as expected when plotting more than one polygon together, but when polygons are plotted individually there is no transparency regardless of the alpha value. plot(x, add=TRUE, alpha=...) works as expected, including for individual polygons.

Is polys() meant to behave like that?

Thanks!

````
library("terra")
packageVersion("terra")
# [1] ‘1.7.23’

# create two lat/long rectangles
pts.geom
#      object part     x    y hole
# [1,]      1    1 -31.0 46.0    0
# [2,]      1    1 -31.0 47.0    0
# [3,]      1    1 -30.0 47.0    0
# [4,]      1    1 -30.0 46.0    0
# [5,]      2    1 -30.5 45.5    0
# [6,]      2    1 -30.5 46.5    0
# [7,]      2    1 -29.5 46.5    0
# [8,]      2    1 -29.5 45.5    0

# Create SpatVector
v <- vect(pts.geom, type="polygons", crs="epsg:4326")

# plot both polygons
dev.new(width=6, height=6, noRStudioGD = FALSE)
plot(v, ext=c(-31.5, -29, 45, 47.5), col=c("red","blue"), alpha=.4, las=1) # works

# Create blank map
dummy.pt <- vect(data.frame("lon"=180, "lat"=90))  # point out of map extent
plot(dummy.pt, ext=c(-31.5, -29, 45, 47.5), las=1,  xlab="Longitude (deg. E)", ylab="Latitude (deg. N)")  # blank map canvas

# plot both polygons at once
polys(v, col=c("red","blue"), alpha=.4) # works

# plot subsetted polygons individually (on blank map)
plot(dummy.pt, ext=c(-31.5, -29, 45, 47.5), las=1,  xlab="Longitude (deg. E)", ylab="Latitude (deg. N)")  # blank map canvas
polys(v[1], col="red", alpha=.4)  # no transparency
polys(v[2], col="blue", alpha=.4) # no transparency

# or one polygon per SpatVector
v.3 <- vect(pts.geom[1:4, ], type="polygons", crs="epsg:4326")
v.4 <- vect(pts.geom[5:8, ], type="polygons", crs="epsg:4326")
plot(dummy.pt, ext=c(-31.5, -29, 45, 47.5), las=1,  xlab="Longitude (deg. E)", ylab="Latitude (deg. N)")  # blank map canvas
polys(v.3, col="red", alpha=.4)  # no transparency
polys(v.4, col="blue", alpha=.4) # no transparency```

[![Red and blue polygons plotted together: have transparency][1]][1]
[![Red and blue polygons plotted individually: no transparency][2]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cJ3z.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5FM5.png
````